# Goldberg variations - chord progression changes between variations

Tags: theory, chord-theory, figured-bass

The Wikipedia article on the Goldberg variations sets out the [chord progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_Variations#Form) which all variations follow. In some bars, different options are separated by commas and it says there are different options taken by different variations.

**What is meant by the comma notation here?** In particular, what options are being indicated? For example, the first label is '3,5,6#'. Presumably one of the options is E major (E,G#,B), corresponding to '3,5' (or perhaps just to '3'?). What are the alternatives? In the case of 6#, is it supposed to be (E,G#,C#), (E,G#,B,C#), or perhaps something else? How many possibilities are being listed here?

Comment: Hi Doktor Mayhem, I'm new to the site - curious why the second question asking for a reference setting out which variation follows which chord options was deleted. It may be a silly question - if so, understanding why might help my confusion!

Comment: you can see the comment on the edit to tell why it was deleted. it says it was because there were multiple questions in a post.

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

By 3,5,6# (Kirkpatrick actually writes "3,5, or 6#" — the "or" making things much more clear) Kirkpatrick is saying that sometimes only the third above the bass is included (3), sometimes a complete root position chord appears (5), and sometimes a first inversion chord (6#).

---

## Kirkpatrick's explanation

Here is and excerpt of what Kirkpatrick has to say about the harmonic structure (see also the image below).

> The fundamental bass is never state entirely in its most elemental form, as quoted here (Ex. 1), not even in the Aria....

> Certain alterations to the fundamental bass are to be found. For example, chords of the sixth are interchanged with their root positions, and *vice versa*. It even happens that a six-four is substituted for a sixth-chord. The bass, the third, the sixth, or even the fifth is occasionally sharpened or flattened. In some places there is a certain interchange or ambiguous hesitation between the fifth and the sixth, with much use of the third alone against the bass, in order to leave this ambiguity free of limitation or definition.

[image: Kirkpatrick's harmonic explanation with illustration]

## Examples

Taking the third measure of Kirkpatrick's outline as an example, instances of each option can be found as follows.

#### 3: Variation 1, m. 3

Variation 1 contains only the bass note (E) and the third above (G), leaving open whether it's a root position E minor chord or a first inversion C# diminished chord. Note that the C# occurring during beat 3 is not part of the bass-E chord. Rather, it's part of an A major chord leading to the D minor chord in the next measure.

[image: Goldberg Variation 1, m. 3]

#### 5: Variation 3, m. 2

In variation 3, the first two beats of measure 2 comprises a root position E minor chord. The C# here is a passing tone and does not affect the harmony.

[image: Goldberg Variation 3, m. 2]

#### 6#: The Aria, m. 3

Here is shown measure 3 of the Aria. It contains the chord E-G-C#, which is a first inversion C# diminished triad, the C# being a raised sixth above the bass E.

[image: Goldberg Aria m. 3]

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed reply. I had looked at variation 1 and incorrectly concluded that the C# was part of the bass E chord - how could I tell that this is not the case? Based on this and variation 3, am I right to interpret your comment as saying that there is no unambiguous conclusion about which option is being taken in each of these cases?

I was going to ask if there is a reference listing out which option is taken by each variation, but perhaps no such definitive list could exist?

Comment: @octopus The primary evidence that the C# is not part of a diminished chord is the prominent placement of A on beat 3 and the "&" of three. A isn't part of either a C#dim or Emin chord, and it's placement draws the ear toward A major. Although Kirkpatrick mentions ambiguous scenarios, I didn't look for one, and Vars 1 and 3 are, in my view, unambiguous. Var 1 is "unambiguously ambiguous" — meaning, it's just a third, with no commitment or even hint at a specific chord; and Var 3 is definitely a root position E minor chord.

Comment: @octopus Regarding the reference: unfortunately, Kirkpatrick seems not to lay out a detailed analysis, and I'm not aware of another one.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers correspond to **figured bass** numerals of interval sizes (adjusted with accidentals as necessary) above the notated bass note. Note that interval sizes with no accidentals are assumed to take their notes from the home key only.

Note that the first appearance of the "3,5,6♯" figured bass numerals is above an E note in the bass. This means that you can play **E-G, E-B, and E-C♯**.

The true Goldberg variations according to your provided https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_Variations#Form are more complicated than just picking among 3, 5, and 6♯. In fact, a good argument can be made that Variatio 5. a 1 ô vero 2 Clav. uses the entire 3/5/6♯ shebang with its use of E, G, B, and C♯:
[image: Goldberg Variation 5, beginning]

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So in the "3,5,6#" example, does that just mean the chord is E, G, B, C#? I'm confused by the text underneath which says "where digits are separated by comma, they indicate different options taken in different variations". I had assumed 3,5,6# would correspond to different options?

Comment: @octopus - Oops, I forgot to investigate that phrase further - turns out that the Goldberg variation actually does ambiguously flip between all 3 options and even combinations thereof. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The measure is a 6# chord. The B is not part of the harmony in this case.

Comment: Note that the B — which would be the chordal seventh — does not properly resolve in the following measure.

Comment: @Aaron - I have a tough time believing that the A at Beat 4.5 of Bar 3 of Variation 5 is a chord tone, and therefore an even tougher time believing that the B approached by leap and departed by step at Beat 4.25 is a nonchord tone, especially since we can explain it as a chord tone so easily and still stay within common practice period harmony.

Comment: (I assume you mean beat 3.5, rather than 4.5). The A isn't a chord tone (unless one interprets it as an anticipation of m. 4's d minor). The chord is C# dim in first inversion.

Answer (score 0):

These are the intervals played above the bass note. As we aren't able to notate them vertically like blockchords they are written with  a comma. Usually the 3 and 5 isn't notated for every one it's clear they are played. 6 means first inversion. 5,6 means the dominant 7th chord first inversion.